# Masking an layerd waveform with opacity in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Is it possible to mask out some parts of an image and also give it the opacity of the named paths? Hard to explain, see pictures below.

I have like that image:

[image: Image without the mask]

On that image, there is no mask attached right now. And I saw some Websites where somebody did with Elementor an image like that.

[image: Image with mask]

Now I can simply make such an image with Photoshop, but the image should change, so it will be a lot of work. I made an SVG With some waves and want to use that as a mask, but when I apply the mask the image disappears. I didn't work so much with CSS masking before, I also tried to look at how the Elementorpage did that, but it seems they are achieving it without masking in CSS (more likely they use JS for that?).

Furthermore, I will append the SVG Code as well inside the HTML Block. If somebody has already done something like that or knows a direction how to look at that.

**The whole code is:**

```css
.event-city-wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.city-image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  mask-image: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<div class="event-city-wrapper">
  <svg id="mask" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
       <path opacity="0.33" d="M473,67.3c-203.9,88.3-263.1-34-320.3,0C66,119.1,0,59.7,0,59.7V0h1000v59.7 c0,0-62.1,26.1-94.9,29.3c-32.8,3.3-62.8-12.3-75.8-22.1C806,49.6,745.3,8.7,694.9,4.7S492.4,59,473,67.3z"></path>
       <path opacity="0.66" d="M734,67.3c-45.5,0-77.2-23.2-129.1-39.1c-28.6-8.7-150.3-10.1-254,39.1 s-91.7-34.4-149.2,0C115.7,118.3,0,39.8,0,39.8V0h1000v36.5c0,0-28.2-18.5-92.1-18.5C810.2,18.1,775.7,67.3,734,67.3z"></path>
       <path d="M766.1,28.9c-200-57.5-266,65.5-395.1,19.5C242,1.8,242,5.4,184.8,20.6C128,35.8,132.3,44.9,89.9,52.5C28.6,63.7,0,0,0,0 h1000c0,0-9.9,40.9-83.6,48.1S829.6,47,766.1,28.9z"></path>
   </svg>
  <img id="image" class="city-image" src="https://dgzi-jahreskongress.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/DGZI24_1140x550small3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't delete `mask-image: url(#mask);` is what you expect?

Comment: @Shuo That was a good Hint, I just change, removed that and adjusted the fill color of the SVG path, that it fits with the back of all other stuff. Was a huge thought mistake on my side. Thought maybe there is like a masking hack where you can achieve this, but this fits also greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This may meet your like given image

```css
.event-city-wrapper {
     margin-top: 50px;
     position: relative;
}
 .event-city-wrapper svg {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
}
 .city-image {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-city-wrapper">
   <svg id="mask" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path opacity="0.33" d="M473,67.3c-203.9,88.3-263.1-34-320.3,0C66,119.1,0,59.7,0,59.7V0h1000v59.7 c0,0-62.1,26.1-94.9,29.3c-32.8,3.3-62.8-12.3-75.8-22.1C806,49.6,745.3,8.7,694.9,4.7S492.4,59,473,67.3z" fill="white"></path>
   <path opacity="0.66" d="M734,67.3c-45.5,0-77.2-23.2-129.1-39.1c-28.6-8.7-150.3-10.1-254,39.1 s-91.7-34.4-149.2,0C115.7,118.3,0,39.8,0,39.8V0h1000v36.5c0,0-28.2-18.5-92.1-18.5C810.2,18.1,775.7,67.3,734,67.3z" fill="white"></path>
   <path d="M766.1,28.9c-200-57.5-266,65.5-395.1,19.5C242,1.8,242,5.4,184.8,20.6C128,35.8,132.3,44.9,89.9,52.5C28.6,63.7,0,0,0,0 h1000c0,0-9.9,40.9-83.6,48.1S829.6,47,766.1,28.9z" fill="white"></path>
</svg>

   <img id="image" class="city-image" src="https://dgzi-jahreskongress.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/DGZI24_1140x550small3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```